# What is the earliest possible location in which VaadinSession.getCurrent() returns non null reference for a new server request?

Tags: java, servlets, vaadin

In my Vaadin application, I am trying to add the current user name to the log4j log pattern prefix.

```
<PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyyMMdd-HHmmss.SSS}|%X{userName}|%t|%-5p| %-100m \t(%c{1}.%L)%n"/>
```

I am looking for a suitable location to put the following line which sets the current userName.

```
MDC.put("userName", userName);
```

Can someone suggest me a hook which gets executed at earliest possible location where `VaadinSession.getCurrent()` returns non null reference?